# Using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, how do I get the value of an Attribute property that is of type Type?

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, sourcegenerators

I have an `Attribute` class used to decorate an assembly for use in C# source code generators.  I am trying to get the value of one of the arguments that is type System.Type.  I can get the values of the other properties just fine.

Here's the attribute class:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
    public class MigrationFunctionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public Type MigrationFunction { get; set; }

        public string MigrationMethod { get; set; }
        public string DependsOn { get; set; }
        public string SqlScriptBucket { get; set; }
        // ATTRIBUTE:  ADD HERE
        public string Branch { get; set; }

    }
```

Here's my usage of the attribute:

```
[assembly: MigrationFunction(MigrationFunction = typeof(MigrationFunctions), MigrationMethod = nameof(MigrationFunctions.MyMigrator), Branch = "@Branch", DependsOn = "Restore")]
```

After receiving the attribute in the `SyntaxReceiver`, I try to build a model from the information:

```
    public static AttributeModel2<IMigrationFunctionAttributeModel> Build(AttributeSyntax receiverMigrationFunctionAttribute, GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {

        SemanticModel semanticModel = context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(receiverMigrationFunctionAttribute.SyntaxTree);

        foreach (var attributeArgumentSyntax in receiverMigrationFunctionAttribute.ArgumentList.Arguments)
        {
            switch (attributeArgumentSyntax.NameEquals.Name.Identifier.ValueText)
            {
                case nameof(MigrationFunctionAttribute.MigrationFunction):


                    Debug.WriteLine(attributeArgumentSyntax.Expression);
                    // ^^^ outputs 'typeof(MigrationFunctions)'

                    TypeInfo t = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(attributeArgumentSyntax.Expression);
                    Debug.WriteLine(t.Type.ToDisplayString());
                    // ^^^ outputs 'System.Type'


                    /// HOW DO I GET THE TYPE HERE, which should be "MigrationFunctions", not "System.Type"???
                    break;
                case nameof(MigrationFunctionAttribute.Branch):

                    var value = semanticModel.GetConstantValue(attributeArgumentSyntax.Expression);
                    Debug.WriteLine(value.Value);
                    // ^^^ outputs '@Branch just fine
                    break;

            }
        }
        
        return null;

    }
```

The model builder method can pick through the arguments as expected, but I cannot figure out how to get the correct type info for the property:

```
public Type MigrationFunction { get; set; }
```

I get `System.Type`, whereas I am expecting to get `MigrationFunctions`.

When I output from, I get `typeof(MigrationFunctions)`:

```
Debug.WriteLine(attributeArgumentSyntax.Expression);
```

As documented in the code, HOW DO I GET THE TYPE HERE, which should be "MigrationFunctions", not "System.Type"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track.  Let's home in on this part:

```
TypeInfo t = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(attributeArgumentSyntax.Expression);
Debug.WriteLine(t.Type.ToDisplayString());
// ^^^ outputs 'System.Type'
```

As you note, `GetTypeInfo` when invoked with `attributeArgumentSyntax.Expression` returns a `TypeInfo` representing `System.Type`.  This makes sense because the declared type of that attribute property is `System.Type`.

You can still get the type you're after (`MigrationFunctions`) but you have to dig a little deeper.  First cast the expression to `TypeOfExpressionSyntax`:

```
var typeOfExpression = (TypeOfExpressionSyntax)attributeArgumentSyntax.Expression;
```

With that you can get the actual `TypeSyntax` representing `typeof(MigrationFunctions)`:

```
var typeSyntax = typeOfExpression.Type;
```

Finally, you can get the `ITypeSymbol` for `MigrationFunctions`:

```
var type = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(typeSyntax);
```

Comment: semanticModel.GetTypeInfo() returns TypeInfo, not Type. How to convert TypeInfo to Type then?